# Should I use libc::c_char or std::os::raw::c_char?

Tags: rust, ffi

I am writing a FFI wrapper for Rust. I have seen usages of both `libc::c_char` and `std::os::raw::c_char`. My knowledge of C is very minimal and I wonder if there is any difference. What should I use if I would like to expose a string to Python via cffi?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I can't answer which is more idiomatic, but I can say that they are the same on 64-bit Linux (the default platform for most online hosted documentation):

[`std::os::raw::c_char`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/raw/type.c_char.html):

```
type c_char = i8;
```

[`libc::c_char`](https://docs.rs/libc/0.2.23/libc/type.c_char.html):

```
type c_char = i8;
```

Looking more broadly across different platforms is a bit more complicated. The standard library [tightly groups all the definitions for `c_char`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.17.0/src/libstd/os/raw.rs#L17-L34), but [libc groups them by platform](https://github.com/rust-lang/libc/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=pub+type+c_char&type=). Considering how fundamental this type is, I'd expect them to be the same on all platforms.

Practically speaking, neither of these definitions are likely to ever change, so there's probably not any stability difference.

My opinion would be to use the one from the standard library version until I needed to use something specific from `libc`, in which case I'd probably switch all the types to the libc variants, just to be consistent.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to @Shepmaster's answer, I'd like to highlight the fact that `libc` does not depend on `std`.

Therefore, if you can't use `std`, you'll have to use `libc`.
This situation can be seen [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/libc/blob/f9ae8e6db5aa57e958aefa6819dc784893c68b0e/README.md#usage).

> Currently libc by default links to the standard library, but if you would instead like to use libc in a `#![no_std]` situation or crate you can request this via:

```
[dependencies]
libc = { version = "0.2", default-features = false }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Rust 1.64 `c_char` is available in the module dedicated to FFI: [`std::ffi::c_char`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ffi/type.c_char.html) or even `core::ffi::c_char`.

It's provided with Rust so it does not depend on an external library like `libc`, and also available in `core` so it's available in `no_std` environments.

If you don't need to support earlier Rust versions, that should be the most idiomatic choice.